# Can reading/writing a NETLINK socket ever fail?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I assume a kernel panic or something equivalently catastrophic could occur, but otherwise is it possible for a send or recv on a NETLINK socket to error out?

Comment: Generally, system calls do extensive checking. If you get a kernel panic from sending a netlink message, that's a serious bug that'd at least be a local denial of service, and possible a security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the point of an `AF_NETLINK` socket is to communicate with the kernel, it's certainly possible *in theory* for a `send` call to fail, as the kernel will inspect the data being handed to it and can decide that said data are nonsense and reject the `send` (with any errno it likes).

More practically, since you supply the data pointer, you can supply an invalid pointer (as with any `send` or `recv` call) and get an immediate `EFAULT` error.

Provided the `recv` buffer is valid and big enough, `recv` generally should not fail (except with things like `EINTR`).

I imagine you can get a more specific answer with more specific code.